# tabular as equation

Tags: tables, equations

[image: **enter image description here**]

Hi how can I make this tabular as equation. I mean putting number at the end,
here is my code for the tabular:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Randbetingelse} \\
    \hline
    1 & $Deflection=\omega=0$  & $ Y(0)\cdot T(t)=0$\\
    \hline
    2 & $Slope=\frac{d}{d x} \omega=0$   &  $ Y'(0)\cdot T(t)=0$\\
    \hline
   3 & $Slope=\frac{d}{d L} \omega=0$     &  $ Y'(L)\cdot T(t)=0$\\
    \hline
   4 & $ 4\cdot E\cdot I\cdot \frac{d^{3}}{d x^{3}} \omega (L,t)=m0\cdot \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}} \omega (L,t)$    &  $4\cdot E\cdot I\cdot Y'''(L)\cdot T(t)=m0\cdot Y(L)\cdot \ddot{T}(t) $\\
    \hline   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure I get what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want the whole table to be numbered as it were an equation?

Comment: just replace `\begin{table}[h]` by `\begin{equation}`  But also `$Deflection=\omega=0$` should be `$\textrm{Deflection}=\omega=0$` look at your image above: the math italic font is designed to make it look _not_ like a word but as a product D time s times f times ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this? I've replaced the `table` environment with an `equation` environment, replaced the `tabular` environment with an `array` environment (no need to type all those `$` symbols...), gotten rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, and put the full words ("Deflection", etc) inside `\text` wrappers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\def\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{array}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\text{Randbetingelse}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
    1 & \text{Deflection}=\omega=0  
      &  Y(0) T(t)=0\\
    2 & \text{Slope}=\frac{d}{d x} \omega=0   
      &   Y'(0) T(t)=0\\
   3 & \text{Slope}=\frac{d}{d L} \omega=0     
     &   Y'(L) T(t)=0\\
   4 &  4 E I \frac{d^{3}}{d x^{3}} \omega (L,t)=m_0 \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}} \omega (L,t)    
     &  4 E I Y'''(L) T(t)=m_0 Y(L) \ddot{T}(t) \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to keep the lines between the rows, I suggest you do so by providing `\midrule` instructions.

Comment: Late comment but do you by any change know how one could include a multi-line equation (say, with multiple cases) into this table?

Comment: @erocoar - You could use an `aligned` environment or a `gathered` environment.

Answer (score 8):

For future reference, it's worth noting that if you already have your table looking exactly how you want it, all you have to do is replace your `table` environment with `equation`, i.e.

```
\begin{equation}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Randbetingelse} \\
    \hline
    1 & $Deflection=\omega=0$  & $ Y(0)\cdot T(t)=0$\\
    \hline
    2 & $Slope=\frac{d}{d x} \omega=0$   &  $ Y'(0)\cdot T(t)=0$\\
    \hline
   3 & $Slope=\frac{d}{d L} \omega=0$     &  $ Y'(L)\cdot T(t)=0$\\
    \hline
   4 & $ 4\cdot E\cdot I\cdot \frac{d^{3}}{d x^{3}} \omega (L,t)=m0\cdot \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}} \omega (L,t)$    &  $4\cdot E\cdot I\cdot Y'''(L)\cdot T(t)=m0\cdot Y(L)\cdot \ddot{T}(t) $\\
    \hline   
\end{tabular}
\end{equation}
```

This should just work - your table will look exactly as it did before (it will be typeset in text mode), and it will be shown inline with an equation number as you wanted.

Comment: Unless the page margins happens to be unusually narrow -- for sure, much narrower than by default -- this approach provides no guarantee that the tabular material will fit inside the width of the textblock. At a mininum, you might want to advise the OP to get rid of all 13 [!] `\cdot` statements; that alone will conserve a lot of space.

Comment: A separate issue: I would quibble with the hypothesis that "if you already have your table looking exactly how you want it". The words "Deflection" and "Slope" should most definitely *not* appear in pure math italics mode. Instead, they should be typeset in either upright ("Roman") or text-italic mode.

Comment: @Mico my answer is mostly for the sake of other people (such as myself, earlier today) who are looking for a solution to the same kind of problem. Specific formatting issues with the OP's table are a separate issue, and are already well addressed by your answer.

Comment: Thanks. How, then, does the suggestion provided in your answer differ from the one David Carlisle made in a comment?

Comment: It is an answer (permanent) rather than a comment (temporary).